# IE 9 box-shadow not showing up

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9

The site is [here:](http://bfcards.edicypages.com/list-of-cards/abyssal-warder-fire)

The shadow in the arrow near the menu is not showing up in IE9. Its working fine in all other browsers including IE7,8,Chrome,Firefox and Opera. Please let me know whats wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your filters you apply to .arrow mess up your box-shadow.

```
progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0.7071067811865476, M12=-0.7071067811865475, M21=0.7071067811865475, M22=0.7071067811865476, sizingMethod='auto expand')
    progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=3, Direction=90, Color='#888888')
    progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius='1', MakeShadow='false')
```

I guess you wanted that to be applied for older IE versions?

Comment: Thanks for this, got the shadow to work. Now the rotate won't. XD

Comment: @UrBestFriend - Glad it worked. Mind if I ask what game is that?

Comment: btw, do you have any idea why the :active selector won't work as well?

Comment: oh, its Battleforge, play for free - its CTG, RTS and MMO hybrid

Comment: @easwee well i tried this on my project but i just seen it puts a shadow to my text instead of my element `<li></li>`

Answer (score 0):

Its works fine here in IE9. Maybe if you press ctrl-f5 it works.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. I'm referring to the shadow in the arrow.